# Doing a JACK programming test I get the response: usage: jack_simple_client

Tags: c, audio, recording, jack

I got this code to successfully compile
http://dis-dot-dat.net/index.cgi?item=jacktuts/starting/wholesimple

How ever when I run it it tells me the following

> usage: jack_simple_client

So I'm thinking it needs some kind of input so i try to run it like the following

> ./jack_simple_client 0

it tells me the following

`jack_client_new: deprecated`

`Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory`

`Cannot connect to server socket`

`jack server is not running or cannot be started`

So how do I got about getting a list of "jack"s?

Comment: I'd guess you need to do ./jack_simple_client <address of jack server>

Comment: I linked the wrong source code. so I just updated that link. Also It looks like when i read up on client/servers i thought it was referring to client/severs with networking but I guess now i need to re-read up on JACK documentation because I now know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to start a jackd server first, usually with the alsa backend.

```
jackd -d alsa
```

now jack_simple_client on another terminal should work

```
jack_simple_client
```

Comment: That seemed to do something. here is my command
 ./jack_test 127.0.0.1

Comment: but then it just does nothing.... Is this expected? i think it might be looking at the code but can I be assured that to be true?

Comment: I have no jack_test here (or is it your own program?). Simply try as above (and be sure to have your speakers and alsa turned on). If that works, you can continue from there (e.g. by looking into the code for jack_simple_client)

Comment: Its actually compiled as jack_test (and the source is called jack_test.c) but I didn't want someone to think the error was in file(So i made it appear in-line with the tutorial i linked). I will try listening into my speakers(I think i had three diff outputs last time I'll try just one instead), I should clear up that it dosen't to "nothing" but it "runs" and then shows a blank line "as if it is running a loop" but "nothing happens".

Comment: Yep looks like that "worked!" I get alot of static (echoes of static). Great! So any advice where I should go from here as far as recording from the microphone? (Any suggested tutorials?)

Comment: I had to unmute my mic from a program (Looks like made with python bindings) called jack_mixer. I turned up my mix and now I can hear my self with this code WEEEEEE......